# How load a base64 encrypted url in a TWebBrowser or TImage?

Tags: delphi, base64, twebbrowser, delphi-10.3-rio, timage

I have [this url](https://pastebin.com/TZw3iTjE) encrypted in base64 that is a animated QRCode.

How i can load it in a `TWebBrowser` (or `TImage`)? Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**

Here was my attempt, but without success:

```
uses
 IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL, GIFImg, ClipBrd;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetStrFromClipbrd: string;
begin
  if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then
    Result := Clipboard.AsText
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('There is no text in the Clipboard!');
    Result := '';
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  GIF: TGIFImage;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      GIF := TGIFImage.Create;
      try
        IdHTTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
        IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
        IdHTTP1.Get(GetStrFromClipbrd, MS);
        MS.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
        GIF.LoadFromStream(MS);
        Image1.Picture.Assign(GIF);
        (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;
        //(Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).AnimationSpeed := 500;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(GIF);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(IdHTTP1);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(MS);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.DoubleBuffered := True;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This not was encrypted with a Delphi base64 function where i also could have the decrypt code.

Comment: Base64 is a standard way of encoding data, not encrypting it.  Any properly implemented Base64 decoder should be able to decode the data.  Look at, I think, TNetEncoding to start with...

Comment: @RobLambden, thank you very much. `System.NetEncoding` worked fine. **PS:** tested saving to disk as a GIF image.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you also, +1 by: *`"data: is not a URL type you can request with TIdHTTP, nor do you need to anyway. All of the image data is encoded directly in the URL string itself."`* . But the encoded url is a animated image, then i suppose that is a GIF and not a BMP like you suggested.

Comment: @BrowJr The `data:` url you showed says `image/bmp`, not `image/gif`, even though it actually does contain a GIF image. Wherever you got the URL from created it wrong.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, then if is `image/bmp`, why it is animated?

Comment: @BrowJr Read what I said again more carefully. I said the *actual image* that is encoded in the url is in fact a GIF, but the url *mis-identifies* it as a BMP.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, ok, understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data:` is not a URL type you can request with `TIdHTTP` (or any other HTTP library), nor do you need to since all of the data is encoded directly in the URL itself. So simply extract the base64 portion and decode it using any base64 decoder of your choosing.

Since your code is already using Indy anyway, you could use its `TIdDecoderMIME` class in the `IdCoderMIME` unit to decode the base64 data to a binary stream, such as with the `TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream()` class procedure.  Then you can load that stream into an appropriate `TGraphic` descendant (`TGIFImage`, `TBitmap`, etc), and then finally you can load that graphic into your `TImage`.

For example:

```pascal
uses
  IdGlobal, IdGlobalProtocols, IdCoderMIME, IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL,
  Graphics, GIFImg, JPEG, ClipBrd;

function GetStrFromClipbrd: string;
const
  CTextFormat = {$IFDEF UNICODE}CF_UNICODETEXT{$ELSE}CF_TEXT{$ENDIF};
begin
  if Clipboard.HasFormat(CTextFormat) then
    Result := Clipboard.AsText
  else
    Result := '';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Graphic: TGraphic;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  URL, ContentType: string;
begin
  URL := GetStrFromClipbrd;
  if URL = '' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('There is no text in the Clipboard!');
    Exit;
  end;

  Graphic := nil;
  try
    MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      if TextStartsWith(URL, 'data:') then
      begin
        Fetch(URL, ':');
        ContentType := Fetch(URL, ',');
        if not TextEndsWith(ContentType, ';base64') then
        begin
          ShowMessage('Data is not encoded in base64!');
          Exit;
        end;
        SetLength(ContentType, Length(ContentType)-7);
        TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream(URL, MS);
        if ContentType = '' then
          ContentType := 'text/plain;charset=US-ASCII';
      end else
      begin
        IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
        try
          IdHTTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
          IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
          IdHTTP1.Get(URL, MS);
          ContentType := IdHTTP1.Response.ContentType;
        finally
          IdHTTP1.Free;
        end;
      end;

      MS.Position := 0;

      case PosInStrArray(ExtractHeaderItem(ContentType),
        ['image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/bmp'{, ...}],
        False) of
          0: Graphic := TGIFImage.Create;
          1: Graphic := TJPEGImage.Create;
          2: Graphic := TBitmap.Create;
          // ...
      else
        ShowMessage('Unsupported image type!');
        Exit;
      end;

      { the 'data:' URL you provided is malformed, is says the image type
        is 'image/bmp' even though it is actually a GIF and thus should
        say 'image/gif'.  To avoid problems with the above code determining
        the wrong TGraphic class to use in that case, you can instead look
        at the first few bytes of the decoded data to determinate its actual
        image type, eg...

        const
          Signature_GIF87a: array[0..5] of Byte = ($47,$49,$46,$38,$37,$61);
          Signature_GIF89a: array[0..5] of Byte = ($47,$49,$46,$38,$39,$61);
          Signature_JPEG:   array[0..2] of Byte = ($FF,$D8,$FF);
          Signature_BMP:    array[0..1] of Byte = ($42,$4D);
          ...

        if (MS.Size >= 6) and
           (CompareMem(MS.Memory, @Signature_GIF87a, 6) or
            CompareMem(MS.Memory, @Signature_GIF89a, 6)) then
        begin
          Graphic := TGIFImage.Create;
        end
        else if (MS.Size >= 3) and
                 CompareMem(MS.Memory, @Signature_JPEG, 3) then
        begin
          Graphic := TJPEGImage.Create;
        end
        else if (MS.Size >= 2) and
                 CompareMem(MS.Memory, @Signature_BMP, 2) then
        begin
          Graphic := TBitmap.Create;
        end
        ...
        else
          ShowMessage('Unsupported image type!');
          Exit;
        end;
      }

      Graphic.LoadFromStream(MS);
    finally
      MS.Free;
    end;

    Image1.Picture.Assign(Graphic);
  finally
    Graphic.Free;
  end;

  if Image.Picture.Graphic is TGIFImage then
  begin
    TGIFImage(Image.Picture.Graphic).Animate := True;
    //TGIFImage(Image.Picture.Graphic).AnimationSpeed := 500;
  end;
end;
```